# Black screen until turning TV off and on again (Rpi OS 64-bit only)

Tags: boot, screen, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, 64-bit

When booting Raspberry Pi OS 64 bit on a Pi 4 (4 GB) the boot process is visible and normal until the "Welcome to Rpi OS" screen — after that the screen turns black (TV still detecting a signal though).

The only way to get a picture of the desktop is to switch to another video input on the TV and the back again. That works every time. Alternatively you could put the TV in standby and start it up again.

- It's not a screensaver
- It only happens in the 64 bit edition of the
  OS, with the same hardware
- Currently using the HDMI0 jack
- 1080p resolution
- Cable practically new and supports 4K
- TV working fine for years with a Pi 3

There's every indication that this is a software issue since it works perfectly fine with a 32 bit OS. What happens after the OS welcome screen that makes it wait for an external event from HDMI before displaying the desktop? Is there a fix?

I found a similar [problem description for libreELEC on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/libreELEC/comments/rhcuil/le_1001_on_rpi_4_8gb_tv_black_screen_until_i/).

Comment: Note to self: exclude power supply as source of problem

Comment: You might've already worked this out, but I seem to be able to get it to work after running updates (in terminal: sudo apt update | sudo apt upgrade) I have to thank you. I was having the same issue and couldn't figure out why, but I never made it past the black screen. Seeing your post, I found out I could power cycle my display. So... Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome. I've switched to Ubuntu now which comes with its own problems, but at least it always outputs an image. And runs Wayland, which is nice.